# Using multiple @media (max-width) CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive website, and am using `@media only screen and (max-width:...)` & `@media only screen and (min-width:...)` to try and size everything.

When using multiple `@media` on one `div`, it does not seem to work.

The fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9ae3r7p/1/) will explain what I am trying to do.

***HTML***

```
<div class="mainNavi2">
  <p> test </p> 
</div>
```

***CSS***

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .mainNavi2{
    border:1px solid orange; 
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 851) {
  .mainNavi2{
    border:1px solid green;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850) {
  .mainNavi2{
    border:1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

What I am basically trying to do is:

> - when the screen is at 800px (or less), an orange border will be displayed
> - for width of 850px (or less) a blue border will be displayed
> - for a width of 851 (or more) a green border will be displayed.

They all work separately, but when all put together, only the `max-width:800px` works.

Comment: Because all the other statements are missing a measurement unit. Only the 800px is specified as pixels. The rest are just numbers. Try adding px behind them.

Comment: Hello, the missing px was me forgetting to add them, but once added (http://jsfiddle.net/q9ae3r7p/4/) it still does the same thing (but only max width 850 is working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the order of your media queries, the orange is being overridden by the blue. Rearrange them and it works:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .mainNavi2 {
        border:1px solid blue;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .mainNavi2 {
        border:1px solid orange;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 851px) {
    .mainNavi2 {
        border:1px solid green;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q9ae3r7p/6/)**

A better approach might be to follow Bootstrap's lead and go mobile-first, using only ascending `min-width` statements:

```
.mainNavi2 {
    border:1px solid orange;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    .mainNavi2 {
        border:1px solid blue;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 851px) {
    .mainNavi2 {
        border:1px solid green;
    }
}
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/q9ae3r7p/8/)**

Answer (score 2):

This will work: http://jsfiddle.net/q9ae3r7p/3/

You had forgotten `px` after the numbers in the other media queries.

Your orange border will never work by the way because the blue media query is overriding it since you have `max-width` on both.

To make this work you should add a media query that activates between a set of screen widths. I take it that you want the blue border between 800 and 850. So the code would look like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 850px) {

  .mainNavi2{
    border:1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

Another solution is to rearrange the order of them so that the `800px` query overrides the `850px` one.

Comment: Hello, sorry, forgetting the px was a mistake (forgot to add them!) Once adding them, the border is blue, but resizing the page does not make the border orange (800px width)

Comment: @user2103072 Ye, I said why this is happening in my answer. I will provide a solution to this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the order of your media queries. Also I think you could do this with less media queries.

```
.mainNavi2 {
    border:1px solid green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .mainNavi2 {
        border:1px solid blue;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .mainNavi2 {
        border:1px solid orange; 
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/q9ae3r7p/7/