# In Bigcommerce's Stencil, how do i make an object show/hide via responsive classes?

Tags: responsive-design, bigcommerce

I'm familiar with Bootstrap and how to make it show/hide objects via responsive classes. However, Stencil appears to use it's own class names, and I'm unable to find reference to them. I have found some Stencil documentation, but I can't find this in it.

I'm using the theme Exhibit and found in the sidebar code that I can make an object *appear* in the drawer on small screens by declaring `class="drawer-item drawer-extras"`. I can't find what is needed to make an object *disappear* from the sidebar, so that it is not in the drawer on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css to hide or transform these items by saying something like

```
@media (max-width 768px) {
    .drawer-item {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

For information on nesting these media queries, you can check [Using multiple @media (max-width) CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294681/using-multiple-media-max-width-css)