# CSS - @media tag not overriding on smaller max width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, media-queries

I'm creating a small react app, and have run into an issue with the css.

My css is laid out in this general format

```
<-->
Shared classes/properties{}
<--->

<--->
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){}
<--->
```

The issue is: When looking at a phone (e.g. iPhone X), it is using the classes from `max-width:991px` instead of `max-width:480px`.

The expected behaviour is:

- `max-width:480` should cover `0px-480px`
- `max-width:991` should cover `481px-991px`

However currently, `0px-991px` is only uses classes from `max-width:991`.

I've tried  `(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)` and its counterpart, but it's still not behaving as expected.

I'm sure there's a gap in my understanding - can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple @media (max-width) CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294681/using-multiple-media-max-width-css)

Comment: An iPhone X max-width is larger than `480px`, that's why it's using styles from `991px`. An iPhone's largest dimension is `812px`: https://yesviz.com/devices/iphonex/ - You need to specify device orientation if you want to apply styles in portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: Doesn't the media tag look at the viewport? Not the resolution? In that case - your link verifies that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried exactly that before and no luck

Comment: @JakeOwen no, look at the correct media queries for the phone. `@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 767px) { /* Your Styles... */ }`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post much code, but from what you posted, I would say you need to add the word "and" between "only screen" and "(max-width: ...)" in both lines:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
  ...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  ...
}
```

From MDN:

> The and operator is used for combining multiple media features
>   together into a single media query, requiring each chained feature to
>   return true in order for the query to be true. It is also used for
>   joining media features with media types.

--> You are combining `screen` and a `max-width` here. Using "and" combines both.

Comment: Sorry I made the correction - i do have that in my code